# Two questions about the first order theory of well ordered sets.

Tags: model-theory, well-orders

Consider the class of well-orderings $W$. Although that class is not first-order axiomatizable, it has an associated first order theory $Th(W)$. Is it finitely axiomatizable? I conjecture that, in addition to the axioms for linear orders, all you need are the axiom that there is a minimum element, and that every element except the last if there is one has an immediate successor. Is this true, or do you need a bit more, or in fact do you need infinitely more?

My second question is, can someone exhibit a model of the first-order theory of well ordered sets that is not itself a well-ordering?

Comment: The order type of a non-standard model of PA seems like it would work for the last question. The countable ones (and I may be recalling this wrong) look like a copy of $N$ followed by countably many copies of $Z$ with the copies densely ordered like the rationals.

Comment: You already claimed to know that well-ordering is not a first-order property, as such that means that there is a model which is elementarily equivalent to a well-order which is itself *not* a well-order. If this isn't the case, then by completeness, well-ordering is a first-order property!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re: the second question there's a very concrete example: a standard exercise using [Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game) is to show that $\mathbb{N}\equiv\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, since $\mathbb{N}$ is a well-ordering, we have $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}\models Th(W)$.

- Here "$\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}$" is shorthand for any linear order consisting of an initial segment isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, a final segment isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and nothing else. For an explicit example, we could consider $(\mathbb{N}\times\{0\})\cup(\mathbb{Z}\times\{1\})$ ordered by setting $(a,b)\trianglelefteq (c,d)$ iff $b<d$ or $b=d$ and $a\le c$.

---

Re: the first question, your guess is correct: any linear order with a least element and such that all but possibly one element has a successor is a model of $Th(W)$. This can be proved via Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games as well, and of course yields many more concrete examples of non-well-ordered models of $Th(W)$, but is significantly more complicated.

Comment: In fact $Th(W)$ is the theory of **discrete** linear orders with a minimum and no maximum.

Comment: @OlivierRoche That's not true - well-orderings can have limit points (indeed, most of them do - the only exceptions being $\omega$ and the finite well-orderings). So e.g. $\omega^2$ is not a discrete linear order.

Comment: Indeed, let's sum up what we know about $T := Th(W)$ : 1) it is the theory of a linear order. 2) $T \vdash \forall x \ \exists y \ \big((x < y) \wedge \forall z \ (x < z) \to (y \leqslant z)\big)$. 3) $T \vdash \exists x \ \forall y x \leqslant y$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche Your (2) isn't right - it doesn't apply to successor well-orderings (you need to allow for the possibility of a maximal element). The second half of my answer says exactly what $Th(W)$ is: the linear order axioms + "There is a least element" + "For all $x$, if there is some $y>x$ then there is some least $y>x$."

Comment: Correct, I had only infinite well orderings in mind...

Comment: @OlivierRoche Even infinite well-orderings can have maximal elements (e.g. $\omega+17$).

Comment: Correct again (thank you for your vigilance). What coud be the completions of (your corrected version of) $T$? eg a completion can specify something like "there are exactly 13 elements who don't have an imediate predecessor"

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the second question : take $(\omega, <)$, which is a well ordering.

In an elementary extension $\mathcal{M}$ of $\omega$, you can realize the (partial) type $\pi(\bar{x}) = \{x_m < x_n \ \big| \ m > n \in \omega\}$ since $\pi(\bar{x})$ is finitely satisfiable in $\omega$.

Hence, $\mathcal{M}$ is not well ordered despite being a model of $Th(W)$.

Comment: Of course, this pushes the question back one step: we still have to find a concrete (proper) elementary extension of $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding first question, an (infinite) axiomatization of $Th(W)$ seems to be given by :

- Axioms of linear orders
- An axiom scheme : for every first order formula $\varphi(x)$, the axiom 
  $$\exists x \ \varphi(x) \to \big(\exists x \ (\varphi(x) \wedge \ \forall y \ \varphi(y) \to x \leqslant y ) \big) $$

These axioms imply that all elements but eventually one have an immediate successor, but the converse doesn't hold : consider $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$. The set of non zero elements without immediate predecessor is definable, and does not have a minimum.